# Find only words inside a HTML div that start with the letter "p" using Backbone.js

Tags: html, search, backbone.js, text

I'm a total newb to Backbone and was wondering what the best way was to find all the words inside a particular HTML div that start with a particular letter using Backbone.js. In this example, I use the letter "p." And once found to wrap that word in a div class. So, for example:

```
<div id="some-div">
  Can you <div class="starts-with-p">please</div> 
  pass the salt and <div class="starts-with-p">pepper</div>?
</div>
```

Comment: dom will find you the `<div>`, but you'll need standard JS string operations to figure out the `p` part.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in vanilla javascript. No backbone required.

```
var el = document.getElementById('some-div');

el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/<.*?>|[^<>]*/g, function(match) {
  if (match.charAt(0) === '<') return match; // skip tags.
  return match.replace(/\bp\w*/gi, '<div class="starts-with-p">$&</div>');
});
```

Matches tags and text.  Returns tags unaltered and scans text for word boundary "\b" then "p" then anything that's a word character "\w".  Replacing with the surrounding div tag.

Comment: thanks @wolfhammer for your help. So I guess there isn't a Backbone.js way to do this (I'm actually curious on how Backbone might accomplish this) or one that isn't overly coded? Thanks again.

Comment: To answer the backbone specific part of this question whilst utilising the snippet from wolfhammer, you would most likely want to keep the 'please can you pass the salt and pepper' string inside the Backbone view itself and do the string building in there. You can then render the result instead of affecting the dom after the view has already rendered.